There is no happening on screen sockets python between two devices (PC-ANDROID)
I tried connect but on the screen there is no happenining
Server.py:
import socket

HOST = "192.168.1.37"
PORT = 8820
    # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))

my_socket.listen(5)

while True:
    karsisoket, adress = my_socket.accept()
    print(f"{adress}'e bağlanıldı")
    message = karsisoket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print(f"Gelen mesaj: {message}")
    karsisoket.send(f"EKSİK OLMA KARDEŞİM".encode('utf-8'))
    karsisoket.close()
    

Client.py:
import socket
IP = "192.168.1.37"
PORT = 8820

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((IP,PORT))

socket.send("SELAMM".encode('utf-8'))
print(socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))

I thought this can be about android then i tried between 2 computer in same WIFI but nothing changed. It still waiting on terminal without any happening.

every network device in computer (wired connection, wifi) has own IP - if WIFI doesn't have IP 192.168.1.37 then server will not work for WiFi. So in server may use 0.0.0.0 to listen for connections on all devices in computer. But still client has to use correct IP for server wifi. On Linux you could use ifconfig in system console to see all devices and all IP.

your code works for me when I run both on the same computer (using 0.0.0.0 in server, and 127.0.0.1 in client). Maybe you have some firewall which blocks access on port 8820
